# Is it possible to use Firebase database with Google Messaging in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM for Push Notification and Firebase Database. But both are pointing in the same JSON and both are different while downloading from the Developers Console. Is there way to migrate?

Comment: You can find a GCM->FCM migration guide on google

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Official Migration Guide from GCM to FCM for Android here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm